# Haproxy and tproxy error

Tags: haproxy, transparent-proxy

I am trying to install haproxy with tproxy. I followed [this tutorial](http://blog.loadbalancer.org/configure-haproxy-with-tproxy-kernel-for-full-transparent-proxy/) but I installed latest versions of kernel and iptables.

Version informations is below:

- HA-Proxy version 1.4.17
- iptables v1.4.9
- Linux-3.0.4

Without the transparent mod, haproxy works fine. But it give error below when I try transparent mode and I see 503 error on the browser.

> Cannot bind to tproxy source address before connect() for proxy lb1.
>   Aborting.

Does anyone know what is that error mean and how to fix it? Thank you for any help...

Comment: Do you mean Linux 3? I very much doubt it works on that. Use the latest 2.X

Comment: @Malcolm - please read our FAQ, this is a comment not an answer, don't use an answer to leave a comment, they just get converted or deleted.

Comment: @Malcolm thank you for your interest. May I ask you to give a specific kernel name which you compiled without tproxy patch and saw it worked?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Self answered by ibrahim in question:

> As Malcolm said, it was about kernel. I compiled and install kernel-2.6.34 and it work.